# Get values from select by location to append to table

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'm trying to calculate the road frontage of polygons by converting polygons to lines and splitting in their vertices, then using select by location to find lines that are within 7.5 meters of the road. I then want to retrieve the road label and append it to the lines table. This is what I have, which find the lines correctly and writes the road information to the lines table, but it doesn't get the correct road info. It doesn't seem to find the road that was used in the select by location tool. Can anyone help?

```
arcpy.PolygonToLine_management("BLPUs", "BLPUs_PolyLine")
arcpy.SplitLine_management("BLPUs_PolyLine", "BLPUsPolyLineSplit")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("BLPUsPolyLineSplit", "BLPU_PolyLineSplit")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("BLPU_PolyLineSplit", "NEW_SELECTION", '"LEFT_FID" <> -1 ')
arcpy.DeleteRows_management("BLPU_PolyLineSplit")
in_layer = "BLPU_PolyLineSplit"
out_layer = "BLPUs_PolyLineSplit"
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_layer, out_layer)
arcpy.AddField_management("BLPUs_PolyLineSplit", "RoadLabel", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management("BLPUs_PolyLineSplit", "DescTerm", "TEXT")
arcpy.AddField_management("BLPUs_PolyLineSplit", "Nature", "TEXT")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("BLPUs_PolyLineSplit", "BLPU_PolyLineSplitt")
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("BLPU_PolyLineSplitt", ["RoadLabel", "DescTerm", "Nature"]) as cursor:
    field1 = "RoadLabel"
    field2 = "DescTerm"
    field3 = "Nature"
    for row in cursor:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("BLPU_PolyLineSplitt", "WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", "C:\Users\Ant\Documents\ArcGIS\OSMaster.gdb\ITN_RoadLinks", "7.5 Meters")
        TABLE = "ITN_RoadLinks_Copy"
        searchRows = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(TABLE,["RoadLabel", "DescTerm", "Nature"])
        for searchRow in searchRows:
            searchRow1 = str(searchRow[0])
            searchRow2 = str(searchRow[1])
            searchRow3 = str(searchRow[2])
        row[0] = searchRow1
        row[1] = searchRow2
        row[2] = searchRow3
        cursor.updateRow(row)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("BLPU_PolyLineSplitt", "BLPUs_FrontageLines")
```